# For Loop in A Set Of Elements in Selenium Python

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, browser-automation

I'm trying to automate one of my manual tasks. I have written the complete script but I am stuck at a point where For Loop is not working.

Here is what I want to do:

This is the set of cards that I want to loop through and perform some actions. For testing purposes, I am just trying to print the title of all the products.
[image: This is the set of cards that I want to loop through and perform some actions]

This is the main code of the image attached before. The class = 'm--t--1' is the main element that contains all these products.
[image: This is the main code of the image attached before.]

And below is the code for a single product. 
[image: The code for the single product]

Now, this is my code which I have written. NOTE: This is not the complete script. I have just written the part of the script where I'm having a problem.

```
#Logging into the website with credentials and saved cookies!
driver.get("https://poshmark.com/login")
time.sleep(5)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_form_username_email"]').send_keys('email hidden')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_form_password"]').send_keys('password hidden')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email-login-form"]/div[4]/button').click()

#Navigating to the closet where these products can be found.
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/header/nav[1]/div/ul/li[5]/div/div[1]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/header/nav[1]/div/ul/li[5]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a').click()

container_of_products = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tile col-x12 col-l6 col-s8 p--2')

for item in container_of_products:
    listing = item.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
    print(listing.text)
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

Comment: Why did you go back a page in the loop?

Comment: @arundeepchohan because I would click on every single product if I succeed in looping. Please, ignore it for now as we are only focusing on printing the text of it. By the way, even if I remove that last line. Loop does not work and the program ends without any error. And you know the result does not print for a single time.

Comment: @arundeepchohan thank you so much for helping. I used css selector and printed the img source by using get_element_by_tag_name but it just printed one result. Loop is not working perfectly. I have so many tasks which are of the same nature and I want to automate them. All the concepts are clear but the only problem is this looping in a set of elements. I hope you can resolve this. Thanks!

Comment: @arundeepchohan Thank you so much. I use this line and it worked

Comment: container = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.tile.col-x12.col-l6.col-s8.p--2')

Comment: Np you are going to end up with a stale element if you click go to another page and come back to it. Unless it's in a new tab.

Comment: @arundeepchohan I have fallen into a new problem. I have been playing with the code to fix this for two hours but each time I get the same results. Can you please review it when you get some time?
Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64274761/loop-only-works-for-elements-in-a-screen-not-after-scrolling

Comment: I actually have a similar answer to that problem

Comment: @arundeepchohan great! Where is that exactly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261087/how-to-scrape-all-steam-id-review-content-profile-url-from-reviews-of-a-game-i/64261735#64261735

Comment: Just remove 500 from the array and the if len >=500 and it should infinitely scroll.

Comment: @arundeepchohan thank you so much. You resolved my issue. Is there anything I can do for you like upvote or anything that can increase your credibility?

Comment: @arundeepchohan by the way, it is collecting 654 links but there are 655. I'm now going to dig this why this happened

Comment: Just accept the answer then and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

tile col-x12 col-l6 col-s8 p--2 is a compound class name it won't work that way. use a css selector and .tile.col-x12.col-l6.col-s8.p--2

```
container = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.tile.col-x12.col-l6.col-s8.p--2')
```